# Upload Photo in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I try to upload avatar using code (I am using Python and Linux os):

```
photo = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ButtonChangePhoto"]')))
photo.send_keys('/home/nataliya/Desktop/puppy.jpg')
```

But the problem I am facing - avatar stays the same.
Question: what is not correct in here?

Update:
here is error i got on Chrome:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
(Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.75)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092   (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.10.0-38-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: What are `wait` and 'WMI'?  I suspect you may need a more specific tag.

Comment: probably needs [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selenium-webdriver/info) tag added, and `wait` appears to refer to http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with selenium you really need to point it at the place you're going to send the keys at. From your example you're setting `photo` to a button. You can't send text to a button. You need to find the text box and send the text to the text box. Then you will need to send a click to the button.

```
text_area = driver.find_element_by_name('text_area_name')
text_area.send_keys('text to send to the text area')

button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('button')
button.click()
```

From the information you've provided this seems like it may help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

As using `send_keys` you are facing `unknown error: cannot focus element` try to use `action_chains` as follows:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(photo)
actions.click(photo)
actions.send_keys('/home/nataliya/Desktop/puppy.jpg')
actions.perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use this

```
driver.find_element_by_id("Locator").send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/image.png")
```

You can use any locator

`os.getcwd()` : returns the current working directory